# Sum a column and put the sum on top of column for dynamic number of rows

Tags: excel, sum

Is there any way to put the sum of a column values on the top of same column. 
For ex: I want to add the values on column A and put the total in the cell A1 and number of rows on column A is dynamic.

Comment: You could do it very easily in VBA, is that an option?

Comment: I did not want to go the VBA option Tim.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: No worries, I just couldn't see anything other than `=SUM(A2:A1048576)` but didn't really want to use that as theoretically in a future version of excel there may be more rows and then that'd be the equivalent of someone still using `=SUM(A2:A65536)` today...

Comment: I agree Tom.  For now I am sure that number records will never reach that number ( as its a SQL query result through database connection from excel), which is why I choose this option.

Answer (score 1):

In **A1** enter:

```
=SUM(A2:A1048576)
```

For versions of Excel 2007 and later.

Comment: I do not want to give the last column as A1048576.  I understand that its higher number, but looking for an option to handle it dynamically

Comment: @bhuvana  using **1048576** is dynamic in the sense that it will correctly add the column regardless of which cells contain values.